# What file systems can Snow Leopard read?

Tags: snow-leopard

I just got a MacBook Pro for my parents, and I need to get their files from a Linux desktop machine that most likely has either reiserfs or ext3 file systems.

I would like to know if Snow Leopard can read these files if I put the HDD in an external HDD case??

Thanks

Comment: OS X definitely can't read FreeBSD UFS file systems.

Comment: The question text does not match the question title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be easier to connect the machines on a network and use rsync, nfs or ftp   to copy data, no extra software would be needed.

If you want to do this you will need [MacFuse](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/) which allows OS X to read other file systems. A tutorial for ext3 is on this [blog](http://ekettoz.blogspot.com/2009/06/mounting-linux-ext2ext3-partitions.html).

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try the network option this coming weekend.

Answer (score 3):

If you are planning on doing this a lot, there are commecial packages too:

http://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-mac/

There is a free alternatives also though through MacFuse/FUSE:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/fuse-ext2/files/

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS X can read (but not necessarily write):

- HFS+ (Mac OS X default format, in plain, journaled, case-sensitive, or journaled/case-sensitive varieties)
- NTFS (but not write, by default)
- FAT (32 and 64 as seen in Christian Correa's comment)

I would expect it can read but I haven't tested it:

- HFS (the older Mac OS file system [Hierarchical File System])
- UFS (Unix File System; older versions of OS X could format and be installed on UFS partitions)

I know for a fact that OS X will not read:

- ReiserFS
- ext* (any of the various versions of the ext Linux file system)
- just about anything else

Check out the Mac OS X column at the incredibly complete [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Supporting_operating_systems) comparing file systems.

Answer (score 0):

Disk Utility can format a new hard drive using the following formats:

- Mac OS X format
- Mac OS X format (Journaled)
- FAT32 (MS-DOS)
- FAT64, also known as exFAT

I believe those would be the same file systems that the operating system can read.